# How can I open a folder in a new window?

Tags: nautilus, window, 13.04, context-menu

It appears that Nautilus no longer provides an **Open in New Window** option in its right-click context menus:

[image: Nautilus context menu ▸ Open in New Tab]

What procedure should I now use instead when I want to open a folder in a new window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while double-clicking it.

I discovered that through trial and error. The documentation of keyboard shortcuts for Files is frustratingly sparse.

Comment: Nautilus 3.14.3 opens new tab with shift-double-click

Answer (score 2):

Simplest workaround:

Right-click the last item in the 'location bar', choose "Open in new window". You have now two identical windows*.

* Well almost; the new window automatically scrolls to the top.

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/335310/495443

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> Preferences, under the Behaviour tab, you can choose to open each folder in a new window, but this would get annoying if it was the default option!