# Nautilus - How to duplicate the current window

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, window

Sometimes I need to open the same directory twice.

If I try to open it from a bookmark, Nautilus sees it is already opened so it simply focuses it.

If I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, the new window opens home.

Is there a simple way to duplicate the current Nautilus window (just keeping the same directory) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Nautilus open in the folder that you want, right click on the folder tab, and choose
open in New Window(in this example I'm opening the folder Downloads) see images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an idea, and it makes me just realize Ctrl + click here does the same thing. Thanks !

Comment: I know, I was simply waiting for an eventual exclusive keyboard controlled solution if any.

Comment: Alt+T will open the same folder being viewed in a new tab.  I can't find a shortcut to open in New Window, the same folder.